# What is the command needed for an API backend Dockerfile?

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerfile

I am new to creating Dockerfiles and cannot figure out what command to use to start up the API backend application. I know that backend applications don't use Angular and that the command to start it is not "CMD ng serve --host 0.0.0.0".

I am attaching the code of the backend Dockerfile and also providing the errors that I am getting when trying to run the container in Docker Desktop below.

I have looked at Docker documentation and Node commands but cannot figure out what command to use to make the API backend run. What am I doing wrong?

**Code:**

```docker
# using Node v10
FROM node:10

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/lafs

# Install app dependencies
# A wildcard is used to ensure both package.json AND package-lock.json are copied
# where available (npm@5+)
COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install
# If you are building your code for production
# RUN npm ci --only=production

# Bundle app source
COPY . .

# Expose port 3000 outside container
EXPOSE 3000
# Command used to start application
CMD ng serve --host 0.0.0.0
```

Errors that I am receiving in Docker Desktop:

```sh
/bin/sh: 1: ng: not found
```

Comment: This really depends on what your server is. You also appear to be copying all files into your image; shouldn't you only copy over the `server` files?

Comment: I just edited the question.

Comment: Thanks for replacing the image with text but that still doesn't answer my question. Is your server Express? Does it have its own `package.json` file? If so, does it have a `start` script (in the `"scripts"`) section? If so, you might just need to execute `npm start`

Comment: Whatever command you'd use to run the application on a non-Docker Node installation, that command probably should be the image's `CMD`.

Comment: I am truly sorry. My server is Express and it does have its own `package.json` file and does have a `start` in the scripts, but it still does not run correctly.

Comment: @DavidMaze I understand but need to know what exact command to use.

Answer (score 1):

From your [original screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DRg0D.png), it looks like you've got a `server` directory. Assuming that's where your Express app lives, try something like this

```bash
FROM node:16 # 12 and older are EOL, 14 is in maintenance

WORKDIR /usr/src/lafs

EXPOSE 3000                  # assuming this is your server port

COPY server/package*.json .  # copy package.json and package-lock.json

RUN npm ci --only=production # install dependencies

COPY server .                # copy source code

CMD ["npm", "start"]         # start the Express server
```